# Twython Not capturing errors

Tags: python, twitter, twython

I am using Twython to capture a stream of tweets from a group of users. I worked for an hour or so quite well (just a few tweets) and then crashed with an HTTP error IncompleteRead.  I saw this discussed in a few posts but never resolved.

Is there any way to capture this error so it does not crash the program?

```
 File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\response.py", line 
331, in _error_catcher
   yield
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\response.py", 
line 640, in read_chunked
    chunk = self._handle_chunk(amt)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\response.py", 
line 586, in _handle_chunk
    value = self._fp._safe_read(amt)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 612, in 
_safe_read
raise IncompleteRead(b''.join(s), amt)
http.client.IncompleteRead: IncompleteRead(0 bytes read, 1 more expected)
```

My code is simple and I see no other options to trap these errors.

```
from twython import TwythonStreamer

CONSUMER_KEY    = '...'
CONSUMER_SECRET = '...'

# Access:
ACCESS_TOKEN  = '...'
ACCESS_SECRET = '....'

class MyStreamer(TwythonStreamer):

    def on_success(self, data):
        if 'text' in data:
            if not data['text'].startswith('RT') and not 
            data['text'].startswith('@'):
                print(data['text'])

    def on_error(self, status_code, data):
        print(status_code)
        self.disconnect()

stream = MyStreamer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, 
ACCESS_SECRET)

# follow is watching for tweets from a user or list of users

users = [25073877, 19905457,1058764970010308611,251918778]

stream.statuses.filter(follow=users, language = 'en')
```

Comment: seems like the error is more to do with  Anaconda and urllib. Are you running this code on spyder?

Comment: No, all the libs and python are anaconda, but I am running under Visual Studio Code

Comment: do you have any other versions of python installed? And have you tried running the python file from IDLE? If not try and let me know the result.

Comment: Thanks.  I am running it in Anaconda terminal now and it has been over 24 hours without a problem.  I am going to assume that Visual Studio Code has some kind of issue, so I will just avoid it.  Appreciate the help.